# PCRE, match expression with *SKIP *F

Tags: regex, pcre

In these two patterns:

```
1: abc)
2: a(bc)
```

I am trying to create a pattern that will match string 1 and return NULL if matched against string 2. I.e. only match if one right parenthesis is present with no left parenthesis. If both a right and a left parenthesis is present, then return NULL. So I am trying:

```
~/ % pcretest
PCRE version 8.45 2021-06-15

  re> "(.*?)\((*SKIP)(*F)|.*?\)"
data> "abc)"
 0: "abc)
data> "a(bc)"
 0: bc)
```

The expression does skip the left parenthesis in "a(bc), but I would like it to return NULL. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you just want to make sure that if there are parentheses in a string, that they are all balanced?

Comment: The above expression contains `.` that matches any char, and `(` and `)`. too. You might want to replace `.` with `[^()]`. See `\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|[^()]*\)`

Comment: The opposite, actually ;) I want to match case conditions in shell scripts,   case "$1" in
    condition). I.e. the "condtion)" line. So in order not to have false matches with right parenthesises, I would like it return NULL.

Comment: Perhaps you can match the balanced parenthesis with skip fail, or match `)` like `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|\)` https://regex101.com/r/anZo92/1

Comment: Why not just use `^[^(]*\)` ?

Comment: @anubhava. that works too. I think I tried something like it, but I forgot the initial anchor. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

This problem doesn't need to use fancy PCRE feature as it can be solved using standard regex with a negated character class (assuming we are not onto complex cases of nested or escaped parentheses):

```
^[^(]*\)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EnPd9f/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^(]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters except `(`
- `\)`: Match right `)`

Answer (score 4):

Using a recursive pattern, you can match a `)` when there are unbalanced parenthesis.

```php
(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|\)
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `(?:[^()]++|(?1))*` Optionally repeat matching any char except `(` and `)` or repeat the first sub pattern (group 1)
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)` Close group 1
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Skip the match
- `|` Or
- `\)` Match a single `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/anZo92/1)